# Snowflake: Sqlalchemy ORM update variant field

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, variant

I have an issue with updating a python model that represents a table in snowflake using sqlalchemy. One of the columns is a variant field and when I attempt to update the model and save it back to the database snowflake complains that the value is not a variant. I've tried passing in the data as a dictionary as well as a json string, neither works.

The model property is defined as:

```
data = db.Column(snowsql.VARIANT)
```

snowsql being an alias for the snowflake-sqlalchemy package, which is installed but it appears to only provide type dialects and not much else.

Does anyone have any experience doing this?

Update:

The data that I am adding is a python list of dictionaries:

```
new_data['data'] = [{'component': None, 'display_name': 'blah', 'key': None, 'row': {'display_name': 'blah', 'type': 'blah'}, 'sub_type': None, 'type': 'blah'}]
```

Doing a json.dumps when setting the variant property:

```
new_blah = Blah(
  data = json.dumps(new_data['data'])
)
```

Results in:

> Expression type does not match column data type, expecting VARIANT but got VARCHAR(8905) for column DATA

The json produced by the dumps:

```
"[{\"component\":null,\"display_name\":\"blah\",\"key\":null,\"row\":{\"display_name\":\"blah\",\"type\":\"blah\"},\"sub_type\":null,\"type\":\"blah\"}]"
```

Alternatively, attempting to assign the list without doing a json.dumps:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 252004: None: Failed processing pyformat-parameters; 'dict' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: Make sure that the value you are passing in is JSON rather than a string.  Can you share the value you are trying to pass into the Variant field?

Comment: Updated with data structures. It's python so I'm just doing a json.dumps to produce a json formatted string.

Comment: Try it with json.load() instead.  I believe json.dumps is turning things into a string, while you want it to be a json payload.  I seem to recall having this issue before, so if json.load() doesn't help, I'll dig up code for you.

Comment: I can't do a load on the list because it's a python object and that only works to parse json strings. The result is: TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'list'

Comment: I can confirm that this is only an issue doing an insert, if I update an existing row with the exact same json.dumps it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, what you're trying is not currently possible. I was having the same issue and even though I got quite a bit into [SQLAlchemy Custom Types](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/custom_types.html#types-sql-value-processing) I can't currently solve it.

The issue is the following:

1. To insert into a `VARIANT` column, you need to use the Snowflake function `PARSE_JSON`.
2. To use said function, you need to be in the context of a `SELECT` clause, i.e. you can't use it with the `INSERT ... VALUES` format (see [Snowflake Community](https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00008DCk08SAD/is-it-possible-to-insert-variant-data-using-an-insert-statement-from-python?t=1607356162647))

I'm not aware of any way to force SQLAlchemy to create a subquery, as it would be required.

In case this changes in the future, here's how far I got:

```py
class SnowflakeJSON(TypeDecorator):
    impl = VARIANT

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        return json_serialize(value)

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        return json_deserialize(value)

    def bind_expression(self, bindparam):
        return func.PARSE_JSON(bindparam, type_=self)

    def copy(self, **kw):
        return SnowflakeJSON()
```

This generates a query like:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (key, data) 
VALUES ('001', PARSE_JSON('{"test": "hello world"}'));
```

However, as per the snowflake community entry above, the `VALUES` format does not work, you need the following format instead:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (key, data) 
SELECT '001', PARSE_JSON('{"test": "hello world"}');
```

As a fallback, you can always use a column type which stores your JSON objects as `VARCHAR`:

```py
class SnowflakeJSON(TypeDecorator):
    impl = String

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        return json_serialize(value)

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        return json_deserialize(value)

    def copy(self, **kw):
        return SnowflakeJSON()
```

With that, you're obviously losing out on the benefits of storing your JSON string as a `VARIANT` data type. However, you can parse this at a later stage, even in a query:

```sql
SELECT PARSE_JSON(text)['test'] from my_table;
```